# How do I access a WCF SOAP service through an LTM proxy via PowerShell?

Tags: wcf, powershell, soap, wsdl, f5

I'm using PowerShell to access a WCF SOAP service.  This is all hunky dory going straight at the WCF endpoint host.  I am using:

```
$request = New-WebServiceProxy -uri ${using:endpoint}"?wsdl" -class "MyService" -namespace "MS"
```

I have a new server that is sitting behind an F5 local traffic manager (LTM).  When I attempt the same thing, I am getting errors because the WSDL that is being returned contains links to the server itself, which is inaccessible, and not to the LTM endpoint.

This results in:

```
The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://myhost/MyService/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
  - Unable to connect to the remote server
  - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.1:80
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (http://192.168.1...ervice.svc?wsdl:Uri) [New-WebServiceProxy], Invalid
   OperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

What do I need to get the LTM host/IP to appear in the WSDL?  Is there some setting in the service's web.config that I am missing?

Comment: I think this is more an issue with the F5 LTM and DNS setup. Your app/service should have a DNS name.  web.config should refer to DNS name and the F5 LTM then does the load balancing using this DNS name.

Comment: OK.  I was hoping I could do this without setting up a DNS entry (yet) as I need to test this out in a running environment before swinging the existing DNS aliases over to the VIP.  That does not appear to be the case.  Setting up DNS and the proper binding for the site seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
```

Without the above, WCF will pick up the url to present from IIS. You could also add host headers to the binding of the site/application that WCF is hosted in, it will use that instead.

Comment: It seems that this requires adding a DNS entry for the VIP.  Adding the VIP address in the "host name" portion of the binding does not work.

Comment: @Colorado.Rob: Did some digging at MSDN since I knew I had done this at some point a few years back. You can also make the web.config change in my edit.